# How to toggle icons on click?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have menu and i want when its open to be up arrow and when its closed it need to be question mark. This is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pmadwvpk/7/

Problem is now when user open menu nothing happend but when i close it arrow appeard. Any suggestion?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function toggleChevron(e) {
    $(e.target)
      .prev('.panel-heading')
      .find("i")
      .toggleClass('fa-question fa-angle-up');
  }
  $('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need both `hidden.bs.collapse` and `shown.bs.collapse`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function toggleChevron(e) {
    $(e.target)
      .prev('.panel-heading')
      .find("i")
      .toggleClass('fa-question fa-angle-up');
  }
  $('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/BG101/pmadwvpk/8/)